# Manifest Merge issues with Lottie

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest, lottie

I was getting started with Lottie when I came across this error. I added the dependency to my `build.gradle`

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.2'
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha06'
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui:1.0.0-alpha06'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Since I added `implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.8.0'` build succeeds but I cant run my application as there is an error in the Manifest Merging.

```
Merging Errors: Error: Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory). Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:5-35:19 to override. app main manifest (this file), line 21
```

Here is my Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.rishav.sanfoundryfer">

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".QuestionActivity"
            android:label="MCQs"/>
        <activity android:name=".TopicActivity"
            android:label="Select Topic"/>
        <activity android:name=".SubjectActivity"
            android:label="Select Subject"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the error has `androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory` points to the fact that the new "Jetpack" support library packages are being used. Seeing that your manifest uses the "older" packages points to the fact that it probably is used by lottie.
You can make sure that this is the reason by inspecting the library.
To resolve the issue you can use an older lottie library, start using the jetpack support library packages or resolve the merge manually. You can take a look at the merged manifest if you navigate to the AndroidManifest.xml and switch to the `Merged Manifest` tab at the bottom of the window.

Comment: BTW, for migrating to AndroidX, you can click Refactor and then select migrate to AndroidX.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

add `'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"'` to `<application>` element at `AndroidManifest.xml:14:5-35:19` to override.app main manifest (this file), line 21

Comment: Ya i read that and obviously tried to do that. smh
It wanted me to provide what to replace it with.

Comment: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" below this line in ur code tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"....

Comment: Yeah i obviously did that mate. That's what I'm saying. After adding this line you need to provide what u want to replace it with.